# set.seed() in knitr and simple execution modes

Tags: r, random-seed

There seems to be an inconsistency between R's handling of the `random.seed()` + `sample()` commands  in the knitter and simple (line-by-line) execution modes. As an example, when I run the R code below line by line (by hitting Control-Enter), I get one set of sampled elements of `x`. However, when I knit the whole documents, I get a different set of sampled elements, although the seed is set at the same number.

I did some research on stackoverflow and elsewhere and the only thing I found that seems to be relevant to my question is the last paragraph of the following page on Yi Hui's website. https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/cache/. After implementing Yi Hui's suggestion, the problem remains (uncomment the second `knitr::opts_chunk` command in the RMarkdown below).

My question is, how to get the same sampled elements regardless of the execution mode?

````
    ---
    title: "set.seed() in knitter mode"
    author: "some author"
    date: "1/27/2020"
    output: html_document
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(knitr)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
    #knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = rand_seed) # Yi Hui's suggestion
    ```

    ## set.seed() in knitter mode.

    ```{r}
    x=1:10
    set.seed(234252)
    sample(x,4)
    # When running the above code manually, I get 
    # [1] 2 4 6 10
    # When knitting the whole document, I get
    # [1] 3 2 6 5
    # How to get the same sampled elements of x regardless of the execution mode? 
    ```
````

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12). 
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit), 
Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15.2. 
Locale: en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8 
Attached base packages: stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base 
Other attached packages: knitr_1.26
Loaded via a namespace (and not attached): compiler_3.6.2 magrittr_1.5    tools_3.6.2     htmltools_0.4.0 yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_1.0.3      stringi_1.4.3   rmarkdown_2.0  stringr_1.4.0   xfun_0.11       digest_0.6.23   rlang_0.4.2   evaluate_0.14
```

Comment: At my console, I get `3 2 6 5`. 
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Thank you Brian for your comment. Do you mean you get the same sampled elements of `x` regardless of the execution mode?

Comment: Yes, with your code as written, I get the same result at the console and when knit. `knitr 1.26`.

Comment: Please update your question with the output of `sessionInfo()` as well.